# How to change the visual of AlertDialog

Tags: android

I need to change the visual of alertDialog of my app, but i don't have idea how do this.

Somebody help me?

my alertDialog:

```
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
            builder.setTitle("title");
            builder.setMessage("My test");
             // Use an EditText view to get user input.
             final EditText input = new EditText(activity);
             input.setId(01);
             input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
             builder.setView(input);
             builder.setPositiveButton("Continue", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                    String comandamesa = ""+input2.getText();
                }
            })
            .show();
```

Comment: What visuals exactly?

Comment: You will want to be much more specific if you want help. You are already changing the "visual" by calling `setView()`. And in making your question more specific, you will probably find better search terms as your question has most likely been answered.

Comment: simple example:http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-custom-dialog-example/

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you made the view in customdialog.xml in your layout folder.

You would create the view using LayoutInflater.inflate. Store the view that is returned and then call setView.  Your dialog should be using the custom view now.